# Can't see pod logs from GKE in Cloud Logging

Tags: logging, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, fluent-bit

I have a GKE cluster v1.22 with the Cloud Logging feature enabled.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JioF.png)

But I can't see any application logs in the Logs Explorer.

Also, I can't see any logs for fluent-bit pod that Google uses to transfer logs to the Cloud Logging.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePkTL.png)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnvnX.png)

It has a default configmap that was created automatically with cluster creation.

API is enabled in GCP.

I can't find any related manuals and topics about it.

I will be very pleased if you help me to deal with it.

upd:

```
I found this in fluentbit.log on the node:

[2022/06/08 08:41:45] [error] [parser] cannot parse '0608 08:41:45.986036' after %L
[2022/06/08 08:41:45] [ warn] [parser:glog] invalid time format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%L%z for '0608 08:41:45.986036'
[2022/06/08 08:41:45] [error] [parser] cannot parse '0608 08:41:45.986083' after %L
[2022/06/08 08:41:45] [ warn] [parser:glog] invalid time format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%L%z for '0608 08:41:45.986083'
[2022/06/08 08:41:45] [error] [parser] cannot parse '0608 08:41:45.986949' after %L
[2022/06/08 08:41:45] [ warn] [parser:glog] invalid time format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%L%z for '0608 08:41:45.986949'
[2022/06/08 08:41:45] [error] [parser] cannot parse '0608 08:41:45.987048' after %L
[2022/06/08 08:41:45] [ warn] [parser:glog] invalid time format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%L%z for '0608 08:41:45.987048'

parsers conf is:

[PARSER]
    Name        docker
    Format      json
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z

[PARSER]
    Name        containerd
    Format      regex
    Regex       ^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) [^ ]* (?<log>.*)$
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z

[PARSER]
    Name        json
    Format      json

[PARSER]
    Name        syslog
    Format      regex
    Regex       ^\<(?<pri>[0-9]+)\>(?<time>[^ ]* {1,2}[^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<ident>[a-zA-Z0-9_\/\.\-]*)(?:\[(?<pid>[0-9]+)\])?(?:[^\:]*\:)? *(?<message>.*)$
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format %b %d %H:%M:%S

[PARSER]
    Name        glog
    Format      regex
    Regex       ^(?<severity>\w)(?<time>\d{4} [^\s]*)\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+(?<source_file>[^ \]]+)\:(?<source_line>\d+)\]\s(?<message>.*)$
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%L%z

[PARSER]
    Name        network-log
    Format      json
    Time_Key    timestamp
    Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if your application writes anything to stdout/stderr:
`kubectl logs <pod_name>`

If it returns nothing then that's why you cannot see any container logs in Logs Explorer for your application.

If it returns anything then make sure you don't have any [logging exclusions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview#exclusions) potentially filtering out your application logs:
In the console menu find Operations section, then go to Logging->Logs Router
Next, on Logs Router Sink named _Default click Dots(More actions)->Edit sink
There, scroll down to 'Choose logs to filter out of sink (optional)' and make sure there are not any exclusion filters with expressions like:
`resource.type=("container" OR "k8s_container")`
`resource.type="k8s_container" AND labels.k8s-pod/app="your_app_name"`
nor any other similar matching your application.

If you find any, you can disable them (or delete them), wait a minute and check Logs Explorer again.